# Acessar uma chave no json

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

Então. Eu estou trabalhando com a api do YouTube para dar GET na quantidade de inscritos de um canal. Tudo da certo. O json chega ao código, meu único problema é tentando pegar o valor da chave **subscriberCount**.

O json que é retornado:

```
{
  "kind": "youtube#channelListResponse",
  "etag": "ji3OqKq0t01wxWAUgA2LLg5GR8Q",
  "pageInfo": {
    "resultsPerPage": 1
  },
  "items": [
    {
      "kind": "youtube#channel",
      "etag": "37_CPNyQ9CbrVL8e1YBzPufbOUE",
      "id": "UCasElAZ8Fn1ACje99uyQK5g",
      "statistics": {
        "viewCount": "63842823",
        "commentCount": "0",
        "subscriberCount": "228000",
        "hiddenSubscriberCount": false,
        "videoCount": "349"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Este é meu código:

```
let url = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=statistics&id=" + id_canal + "&key=" + config.youtubetoken
request(url, function (error, response, body) {
   console.log(body.items[0].statistics.subscriberCount);
});
```

e meu erro é este:

```
                console.log(body.items[0].statistics.subscriberCount);
                                  ^
TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
```

Tentei suporte no stack overflow americano, mas me deram um simples "tópico duplicado", quando o tópico não tinha nada a ver com o meu.
Por favor, me ajudem.

Obrigado,
Gustavo.

Comment: Já tentou dar um `console.log(body)` para ver o que você está, de fato, tentando acessar? O próprio erro diz exatamente o que está acontecendo — `TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined` mostra que `body.items` é `undefined`. Por conta disso, você não pode fazer `body.items[0]`. É a mesma coisa que `undefined[0]`. Por isso a importância de dar o `console.log` ou algum outro modo de _debug_. A estrutura de `body` provavelmente não é o que você espera.

Comment: parece que vc recebe um objeto e não um array, tira o `[0]` e veja se `body.items.statistics.subscriberCount` te retorna algo.

Comment: @Colasanto
Ele me retorna um erro. http://prntscr.com/us5umj

Comment: @LuizFelipe este é o body retornado pela api e enviada no console: http://prntscr.com/us5uzk

Comment: e o body como o @LuizFelipe disse ? retorna algo ?

Comment: `typeof body` é `object` ou `string`?

Comment: @LuizFelipe `string` (http://prntscr.com/us5xqs -- http://prntscr.com/us5xtu)

Comment: Aí está o problema. Converta a `string` para JSON ou acerte `request` para o fornecer os dados no tipo adequado.

Comment: Estava desde ás 3 horas da tarde pensando qual poderia ser o problema, e vocês resolveram em 11 minutos. Sério mesmo, ajudou muito :) @LuizFelipe

Comment: `items` é um array, precisa fazer uma iteração (for por exemplo) para ler os valores, ou usar o índice: `body.items[0].statistics`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se estiver usando a lib [request](https://github.com/request/request), o problema é que o parâmetro "body"  da função é uma string, não um objeto do JavaScript. Você precisa transformá-lo num objeto antes de acessar as props do mesmo. Tente:

```js
request(url, function (error, response, body) {
   //Faz parsing do valor de body, para obter um objeto
   const data = JSON.parse(body);

   //Acessa o array items que está dentro de 'data'
   console.log(data.items[0].statistics.subscriberCount);
});
```